# scheduled task history missing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

this is a bit of weird one ... so we have a server that runs a series of scheduled tasks to do our EDI processing. For some reason, the history for all of them stops last week on 8/16 even though these tasks have been running for over a year. I've checked the last reboot time for the server and it was on 7/17, since then it's been up and hasn't been restarted mainly because there's several developers that log into this server.

Is there a specific event ID I can look for to see if one of these users deleted the task history? I checked the RDP logs and it only shows one user logging in on 8/14. Or is there a setting that clears out the history for scheduled tasks after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

The history is stored in the following event-log:

```
Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
```

You can see this log by opening the Windows Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Log -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Task Scheduler -> Operational

You'll see all the logs of all your tasks (the "History" tab in the task scheduler is only a filtered view of this log). If this log is disabled, nothing will show up in the "History" tab of the Task Scheduler.

You can right-click on this log -> Properties, and review the settings (what happens when the log is full, and so on...)

If you want to know whether someone deleted the content, you can look for Event ID `104`, source `EventLog` in the `System` log and check that the deleted log name is `Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational`